# Move field names in object containing _ (underscore) to as a nested property after splitting the field name by _

Tags: javascript, web, lodash, underscore.js

i have an object

```
{
  "name" : "foo",
  "tag_name" : "grocery",
  "tag_id" : "id",
  "tag_nested_id" : "123",
}
```

I want the output as

```
{
  "name" : "foo",
  "tag" : {
    "name" : "grocery",
    "id" : "id",
    "nested" : {
      "id" : "123"
    }
  }

}
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this using lodash/underscore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No external libraries required, vanilla JS split on `_` and `.reduce`

```js
const data = {
  "name" : "foo",
  "tag_name" : "grocery",
  "tag_id" : "id",
  "tag_nested_id" : "123"
};

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((object, [key, val]) => {
  const splitKey = key.split('_');
  const last = splitKey.pop();
            
  splitKey.reduce((obj, x) => obj[x] ??= {}, object)[last] = val;
  
  return object;
}, {})
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by mani is as good as it gets, but with Underscore, we can create a version that is backwards compatible with older environments:

```js
var data = {
  "name" : "foo",
  "tag_name" : "grocery",
  "tag_id" : "id",
  "tag_nested_id" : "123"
};

var result = _.reduce(data, function(object, val, key) {
  var splitKey = key.split('_');
  var last = splitKey.pop();
            
  _.reduce(splitKey, function(obj, part) {
    return obj[part] = obj[part] || {};
  }, object)[last] = val;
  
  return object;
}, {})
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.4/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```